# Is this $f(x)$ answer correct in regards to functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x) = 2x+4$ for $x=5 $

$f(5) = 2 × 5 + 4 = 14$

Our answer is: $f(5) = 14$

Why is our answer $14$? Because we had everything? $5 \times 2$ is $10$, plus $4$ is $14$. Correct reasoning for the answer: $f(5) = 14$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's correct and your reasoning is fine. You might want to include the word "substitution": given the input $x = 5$, we substitute $5$ for $x$ in $f(x) = 2x+4$  to yield the function value at $x=5\;$:  $f(5) = 2(5) + 4 = 14$.

Comment: Yes the word "substitution" improves the answer and makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. If $f(x)=2x+4$, then $f(5)=2(5)+4=14$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the notation $f(x) = \ldots$ means if you want to compute $f(x)$ for any value $x$, plug it into the right-hand side. So if
$$f(x) = 2x+4$$
then
$$f(5) = 2 (5) + 4 = 14$$
as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Every single point on the graph of a function $f(x)$ must have coordinates in the form $(x, \ f(x))$. Think of $f(x)$ like a machine, where $f$ is the actual machine, and $x$ is what you input. The "machine" is telling you: "If you input any $x$ into me, I will spit out $2x+4$!" So what if we input a value of $x=5$ into the machine? Remember  it will give us a value of $2\cdot x+4$. Because $x=5$, our machine gives us $2\times 5+4$, which equals $14$. We write this as $f(5)=14$.

Remember what I said about every point having the coordinates $(x$, $f(x))$? We now know that one of the points on the graph is $(5, \ f(5))$, which is equal to $(5, \ 14)$. Graph the function $f(x)=2x+4$, and see if $(5, \ 14)$ is on the graph. Amazing, right? Haha hope I helped!!!